# SwiftUI in ObjectiveC Project - List works in preview, not when it is run

Tags: objective-c, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a very big objective-c project and am trying to incorporate SwiftUI slowly. I have been able to successfully implement some screens in swiftUI classes which are called from Objective-c classes.

One strange bug am facing now is that **List** is not visible when the app is run. It is visible in preview though. And also when I replace List with VStack, it appears fine when the app is run. If I make a standalone SwiftUI app and run this code, then too it runs fine. The issue is only when I call this class from objective-c class.

**Attached images**

[Xcode Preview Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqWAK.png)

[Device Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMAYz.png)

**Code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct InfoShareView: View {
    var body: some View {
             List{
                    Text("First Line")
                    Text("Second Line")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
        }

}

struct InfoShareView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        InfoShareView()
    }
}
```

And here is the call to InfoShareView

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class AboutViewControllerSwift: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swiftController = UIHostingController(rootView: InfoShareView())
        addChild(swiftController)

        swiftController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        view.addSubview(swiftController.view)

        swiftController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        swiftController.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

     }


}
```

And here is the call from objective-c class

```
AboutViewControllerSwift *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewControllerSwift alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.nvgController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:aboutViewController];
self.window.rootViewController=self.nvgController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to constraints, try use instead following

```
    ...
    view.addSubview(swiftController.view)

    swiftController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    swiftController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    swiftController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    swiftController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the last line of viewdidload worked for me:

```
swiftController.view.frame = self.view.frame
```